# Uploading epub to Amazon S3

Tags: input, amazon-s3, mime-types

I am using the application/xhtml+xml as the MIME type for epub file upload form in the input html element accept="application/xhtml+xml. Amazon S3 upload fails. What should be the right MIME type for epub? File upload works for pdf and mobi with the application/pdf and application/x-mobipocket-ebook as the mime types for those formats.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with uploading epub files to S3 and finally got it working with MIME type `application/epub+zip`. If you are using PUT request with server-side signing, be sure your MIME types match. MIME type on the third line of string to sign must match with content-type header field of your request.

Comment: mime-types gem provides the mime-type if the name of the file is given.